# Looping over columns with rms::Predict

Tags: r

I'm writing a function to loop iteratively through each element of a character vector, do some things, and append each output into an appropriate list. Within the loop, one of the things I'm doing uses the ith element of my list of characters as an argument to it. But I get the following error:
`Error in Predict(model_fit,vars[i]) : predictor(s) not in model: c("[","vars","i")` 
After researching a bit about it, I tried to create a data promise in order to reference the ith element of the vars vector which had not been evaluated yet by modifying my function as so: `Predict(model_fit,substitute(vars[i],env = as.list(vars))` which output a similar error message about the predictor(s) not being in the model. Any clues as to how I can correctly code this so that the `Predict()` function accurately references the vector element I want?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
data(iris)
library(rms)

iris$binomial_species <- ifelse(iris$Species=='setosa',1,0)
vars <- colnames(iris)

dd <- datadist(iris)
options(datadist='dd')

for (i in seq(length(vars))) {
  fit <- lrm(binomial_species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data = iris)
  Predict(fit,substitute(vars[i],env=as.list(vars))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a character value for the column name, use the `name=` parameter. So these are all the same

```
Predict(fit, Sepal.Length)
Predict(fit, name="Sepal.Length")
myvar <- "Sepal.Length"
Predict(fit, name=myvar)
```

So in your loop you can do

```
for (i in seq(length(vars))) {
  fit <- lrm(binomial_species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data = iris)
  Predict(fit, name=vars[i])
}
```

No need for `substitute()` or any non-standard evaluation here.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think this has given me what I needed

Comment: Say I wanted two variables to vary within my ```Predict()``` function. But the second variable (let's call it ```Variable2```) will always be the same. Would the syntax of the function be: ```Predict(fit, name = c(vars[i],"Variable2")```?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build the call to `Predict` and `eval` it. You aren't storing the result anywhere, so you should probably put the results of `Predict` in a list. The easiest way to do this is `lapply` instead of a loop. Also, you don't need to run the fit every time you loop. Lastly, you can't loop through all the `vars` because they include "Species", which isn't in your model, and "binomial_species", which is the dependent variable:

```r
library(rms)

iris$binomial_species <- ifelse(iris$Species=='setosa', 1, 0)

fit <- lrm(binomial_species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + 
                              Petal.Width, data = iris)

result <- lapply(colnames(iris)[-c(5:6)], function(var){
  eval(as.call(list(quote(Predict), x = fit, as.name(var))))
})

str(result)
#> List of 4
#>  $ :Classes ‘Predict’ and 'data.frame':  200 obs. of  7 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:200] 4.6 4.61 4.63 4.64 4.65 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:200] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:200] 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 4.35 
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:200] 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 ...
#>   ..$ yhat        : num [1:200] -18.3 -18.2 -18.2 -18.1 -18.1 ...
#>   ..$ lower       : num [1:200] -429 -425 -422 -419 -415 ...
#>   ..$ upper       : num [1:200] 392 389 386 382 379 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ dim     : Named int [1:4] 200 1 1 1

#> (...etc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are right in your critiques. However, the reproducible example was an extremely simplified version of what I'm doing, and as such, I really only created it to replicate the error message. In reality, I am storing my ```Predict()``` results and also do need to re-fit my model each time.

Comment: @cliftjc1 fair enough. Does the "building a call" method work for you?

Comment: it is possible that the ```lapply``` family of functions could be a nice alternative to writing a loop. Can you elaborate a little more  on the logic of your ```eval()``` function?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, I'm not familiar with the "building a call" method by name

Comment: @cliftjc1 the `as.call` part allows you to transform a list of language objects into a call to a function. We put `Predict`, the function name, as the first argument in our list, then any subsequent function parameters as named items in the list. We then turn that into a call with `as.call` and finally `eval` or evaluate that call. Although this works, it is not as simple and idiomatic as @MrFlick's answer (I wasn't aware you could use `name = `), though I would probably take the `lapply` part of my answer as part of your final workflow

Comment: thanks for elaborating, really appreciate it. I'll have to look into this method further since I'm always trying to improve my coding skills in R!